# Unit test ASP.NET MVC 5 Controller with async Task<ActionResult>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

Currently I am trying to do some unit test for the Controller and the ViewModel. My Controller function is like this:
[image]
It calls a private method to get user information as a helper function:
[image]

And store the user information in a viewModel then push the viewModel to the client-side.

The Question is how can I do uniting testing for this controller and the associated viewModel?

Here is my unit test case: 
[image]

It returns a Task, which has no viewModel data. How can I access the data related to the viewModel?

Let me know if the information I gave is inadequate.

Comment: paste your code instead of images. Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unit test should look like this:
(NUnit example)

```
[Test]
public async Task ShouldGetValidViewObject_async()
{
    var result = await _controller.Index("644405", DateTime.Now);
    Assert.// your assertion goes here
}
```

Or like this (sync)

```
[Test]
public void ShouldGetValidViewObject()
{
    var result = _controller.Index("644405",DateTime.Now).Result;
    Assert.// your assertion goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should `await` the async method and you should follow "async all the way" rule.

```
var result = await _controller.Index("644405",DateTime.Now);
```

And you have to change your unit test method as `async`.